# Add/Delete table rows dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add/delete table rows following [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_table_insertrow)  and  [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_table_deleterow).

Here's my code:

**HTML Form**

```
<div id="POItablediv">
    <input type="button" id="addPOIbutton" value="Add POIs"/><br/><br/>
    <table id="POITable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>POI</td>
            <td>Latitude</td>
            <td>Longitude</td>
            <td>Delete?</td>
            <td>Add Rows?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" readonly=true/></td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" readonly=true/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add More POIs" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow()
{
    var x=document.getElementById('POITable').insertRow(1);
    var c1=x.insertCell(0);
    var c2=x.insertCell(1);
    c1.innerHTML="NEW CELL1";
    c2.innerHTML="NEW CELL2";
}
```

Now, as you can see, In my table I have text fields and buttons. What I want:

1. Just to repeat the structure of the row. I can't do it right now since innerHTM just takes texts. How can I insert a textfield or label?
2. The ids of the textfields should also be different since I'll retrieve the values later to put it in a database.
3. I want to put a function to increment the number of POIs as well

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could just clone the first row that has the inputs, then get the nested inputs and update their ID to add the row number (and do the same with the first cell).

```
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow()
{
    var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
       // deep clone the targeted row
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
       // get the total number of rows
    var len = x.rows.length;
       // set the innerHTML of the first row 
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

       // grab the input from the first cell and update its ID and value
    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';

       // grab the input from the first cell and update its ID and value
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';

       // append the new row to the table
    x.appendChild( new_row );
}
```

Demo below

```js
function deleteRow(row) {
  var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow() {
  console.log('hi');
  var x = document.getElementById('POITable');
  var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = x.rows.length;
  new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

  var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.id += len;
  inp1.value = '';
  var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.id += len;
  inp2.value = '';
  x.appendChild(new_row);
}
```

```html
<div id="POItablediv">
  <input type="button" id="addPOIbutton" value="Add POIs" /><br/><br/>
  <table id="POITable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>POI</td>
      <td>Latitude</td>
      <td>Longitude</td>
      <td>Delete?</td>
      <td>Add Rows?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox" /></td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" readonly=true/></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add More POIs" onclick="insRow()" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! .. Worked like a piece of cake!

Comment: @Pow: You're welcome. I put together [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/dyuh8/). This one places your header row in a `<thead>` element, and the rest in a `<tbody>` element. Additionally, I updated to code to update the row numbers and IDs when deleting a row, and moved some of the code into its own function.

Comment: I have one more concern. What if I don't have any created row? Suppose I want to do the exact same thing. But the 2nd row (that is being cloned) does not exist initially.

Comment: @Pow: Using the example in my comment above, change the line that makes an initial clone from the first row to this: `clone = tbody.removeChild(tbody.rows[0]);`. So you'd send that row from the server, and remove it right away, storing it in `clone`. Then create another button that will add that initial row. It could be that you'd just want a single button outside the table for adding rows anyway since there's not much reason to have the same button repeating over and over in the table.

Comment: everything is fine but cloned rows its not showing inside tbody how can i show this in tbody

Answer (score 4):

### Easy Javascript Add more Rows with delete functionality

Cheers !

```
<TABLE id="dataTable">
<tr><td>
               <INPUT TYPE=submit name=submit id=button class=btn_medium VALUE=\'Save\'  >
               <INPUT type="button" value="AddMore" onclick="addRow(\'dataTable\')" class="btn_medium"    /> 
</td></tr>

<TR>
<TD> 
                <input type="text" size="20" name="values[]"/> <br><small><font color="gray">Enter Title</font></small> 
</TD>
</TR>
</table>



<script>


function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(0);
       cell3.innerHTML = cell3.innerHTML +' <input type="text" size="20" name="values[]"/> <INPUT type="button"  class="btn_medium" value="Remove" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);" /><br><small><font color="gray">Enter Title</font></small>';
  //cell3.innerHTML = cell3.innerHTML +' <input type="text" size="20" name="values[]"/> <INPUT type="button"  class="btn_medium" value="Remove" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML=\'\';" /><br><small><font color="gray">Enter Title</font></small>';       
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems a lot cleaner than the answer above...

```
<script>
var maxID = 0;
function getTemplateRow() {
var x = document.getElementById("templateRow").cloneNode(true);
x.id = "";
x.style.display = "";
x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace(/{id}/, ++maxID);
return x;
}
function addRow() {
var t = document.getElementById("theTable");
var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var r = rows[rows.length - 1];
r.parentNode.insertBefore(getTemplateRow(), r);

}
</script>


<table id="theTable">
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>name</td>
</tr>
<tr id="templateRow" style="display:none">
<td>{id}</td>
<td><input /></td>
</tr>
</table>


<button onclick="addRow();">Go</button>
```

Comment: Thanks ... Yes I have to I guess :)

Comment: @BradLaney Why learning jQuery for something like this? I don't have nothing against jQuery but, so much people relies on jQuery for so simple things which can be done using pure JS. For few years people will forgot about, even, basics of JS.

Comment: For prototyping there's not much better.

Answer (score 2):

If you put a delete button on each row, then:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="Delete row" onclick="deleteRow(this);">
  <td><input type="text">
  <td><input type="text">
```

And the deleteRow function can be:

```
function deleteRow(el) {
    // while there are parents, keep going until reach TR 
    while (el.parentNode && el.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'tr') {
        el = el.parentNode;
    }

    // If el has a parentNode it must be a TR, so delete it
    // Don't delte if only 3 rows left in table
    if (el.parentNode && el.parentNode.rows.length > 3) {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
}
```

If all your rows have the same content, it will be much faster to add a row by cloning an existing row:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    if (!table) return;

    var newRow = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true);

    // Now get the inputs and modify their names 
    var inputs = newRow.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        // Update inputs[i]
    }

    // Add the new row to the tBody (required for IE)
    var tBody = table.tBodies[0];
    tBody.insertBefore(newRow, tBody.lastChild);
}
```

Comment: this adds new row before last row. How to add new row after last row?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a row to a table in the most easiest way like this :-

> I found this as an easiest way to add row . The awesome thing about this is that it doesn't change the already present table contents even if it contains input elements .

```
row = `<tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>`
$("#table_body tr:last").after(row) ;
```

Here `#table_body` is the id of the table body tag .

Answer (score 1):

1 & 2: innerHTML can take HTML as well as text. You could do something like:

`c1.innerHTML = "<input size=25 type=\"text\" id='newID' readonly=true/>";`

May or may not be the best way to do it, but you could do it that way.

3: I would just use a global variable that holds the number of POIs and increment/decrement it each time.

Answer (score 1):

**Add or Delete row(s) dynamically!**

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <style type="text/css">
        .democlass{
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            for(var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            }

            row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
            for(var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            }

            row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
            for(var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[2].cells[i].innerHTML;
            }

            row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
            for(var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                if(i == (colCount - 1)) {
                    newcell.innerHTML = "<INPUT type=\"button\" value=\"Delete Row\" onclick=\"removeRow(this)\"/>";
                } else {
                    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[3].cells[i].innerHTML;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * This method deletes the specified section of the table
         * OR deletes the specified rows from the table.
         */
        function removeRow(src) {

            var oRow = src.parentElement.parentElement;
            var rowsCount = 0;
            for(var index = oRow.rowIndex; index >= 0; index--) {

                document.getElementById("dataTable").deleteRow(index);
                if(rowsCount == (4 - 1)) {
                    return;
                }
                rowsCount++;
            }
            //once the row reference is obtained, delete it passing in its rowIndex
            /* document.getElementById("dataTable").deleteRow(oRow.rowIndex); */
        }
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <form name="myForm">
        <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
            <TR>
                <TD>
                    <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    Code
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <INPUT type="text" name="txt"/>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    Select Country
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <SELECT name="country">
                        <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
                        <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
                        <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
                        <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
                        <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
                    </SELECT>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD>
                    First Name
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <INPUT type="text" name="txt1"/>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    Last Name
                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <INPUT type="text" name="txt2"/>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD>Phone</TD>
                <TD>
                    <INPUT type="text" name="txt3"/>
                </TD>
                <TD>Address</TD>
                <TD>
                    <INPUT type="text" name="txt4" class="democlass"/>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD>
                    &nbsp;
                </TD>
                <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD>
                    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here Is full code with HTML,CSS and JS.**

```
<style><style id='generate-style-inline-css' type='text/css'>
    body {
        background-color: #efefef;
        color: #3a3a3a;
    }

    a,
    a:visited {
        color: #1e73be;
    }

    a:hover,
    a:focus,
    a:active {
        color: #000000;
    }

    body .grid-container {
        max-width: 1200px;
    }

    body,
    button,
    input,
    select,
    textarea {
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    }

    .entry-content>[class*="wp-block-"]:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    }

    .main-navigation .main-nav ul ul li a {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    @media (max-width:768px) {
        .main-title {
            font-size: 30px;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 30px;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 25px;
        }
    }

    .top-bar {
        background-color: #636363;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .top-bar a,
    .top-bar a:visited {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .top-bar a:hover {
        color: #303030;
    }

    .site-header {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #3a3a3a;
    }

    .site-header a,
    .site-header a:visited {
        color: #3a3a3a;
    }

    .main-title a,
    .main-title a:hover,
    .main-title a:visited {
        color: #222222;
    }

    .site-description {
        color: #757575;
    }

    .main-navigation,
    .main-navigation ul ul {
        background-color: #222222;
    }

    .main-navigation .main-nav ul li a,
    .menu-toggle {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .main-navigation .main-nav ul li:hover>a,
    .main-navigation .main-nav ul li:focus>a,
    .main-navigation .main-nav ul li.sfHover>a {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #3f3f3f;
    }

    button.menu-toggle:hover,
    button.menu-toggle:focus,
    .main-navigation .mobile-bar-items a,
    .main-navigation .mobile-bar-items a:hover,
    .main-navigation .mobile-bar-items a:focus {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .main-navigation .main-nav ul li[class*="current-menu-"]>a {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #3f3f3f;
    }

    .main-navigation .main-nav ul li[class*="current-menu-"]>a:hover,
    .main-navigation .main-nav ul li[class*="current-menu-"] .sfHover>a {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #3f3f3f;
    }

    .navigation-search input[type="search"],
    .navigation-search input[type="search"]:active {
        color: #3f3f3f;
        background-color: #3f3f3f;
    }

    .navigation-search input[type="search"]:focus {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #3f3f3f;
    }

    .main-navigation ul ul {
        background-color: #3f3f3f;
    }

    .main-navigation .main-nav ul ul li a {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .main-navigation .main-nav ul ul li:hover>a,
    .main-navigation .main-nav ul ul li:focus>a,
    .main-navigation .main-nav ul ul li.sfHover>a {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #4f4f4f;
    }

    .main-navigation . main-nav ul ul li[class*="current-menu-"]>a {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #4f4f4f;
    }

    .main-navigation .main-nav ul ul li[class*="current-menu-"]>a:hover,
    .main-navigation .main-nav ul ul li[class*="current-menu-"] .sfHover>a {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #4f4f4f;
    }

    .separate-containers .inside-article,
    .separate-containers .comments-area,
    .separate-containers .page-header,
    .one-container .container,
    .separate-containers .paging-navigation,
    .inside-page-header {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .entry-meta {
        color: #595959;
    }

    .entry-meta a,
    .entry-meta a:visited {
        color: #595959;
    }

    .entry-meta a:hover {
        color: #1e73be;
    }

    .sidebar .widget {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .sidebar .widget .widget-title {
        color: #000000;
    }

    .footer-widgets {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .footer-widgets .widget-title {
        color: #000000;
    }

    .site-info {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #222222;
    }

    .site-info a,
    .site-info a:visited {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .site-info a:hover {
        color: #606060;
    }

    .footer-bar .widget_nav_menu .current-menu-item a {
        color: #606060;
    }

    input[type="text"],
    input[type="email"],
    input[type="url"],
    input[type="password"],
    input[type="search"],
    input[type="tel"],
    input[type="number"],
    textarea,
    select {
        color: #666666;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        border-color: #cccccc;
    }

    input[type="text"]:focus,
    input[type="email"]:focus,
    input[type="url"]:focus,
    input[type="password"]:focus,
    input[type="search"]:focus,
    input[type="tel"]:focus,
    input[type="number"]:focus,
    textarea:focus,
    select:focus {
        color: #666666;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-color: #bfbfbf;
    }

    button,
    html input[type="button"],
    input[type="reset"],
    input[type="submit"],
    a.button,
    a.button:visited,
    a.wp-block-button__link:not(.has-background) {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #666666;
    }

    button:hover,
    html input[type="button"]:hover,
    input[type="reset"]:hover,
    input[type="submit"]:hover,
    a.button:hover,
    button:focus,
    html input[type="button"]:focus,
    input[type="reset"]:focus,
    input[type="submit"]:focus,
    a.button:focus,
    a.wp-block-button__link:not(.has-background):active,
    a.wp-block-button__link:not(.has-background):focus,
    a.wp-block-button__link:not(.has-background):hover {
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #3f3f3f;
    }

    .generate-back-to-top,
    .generate-back-to-top:visited {
        background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .generate-back-to-top:hover,
    .generate-back-to-top:focus {
        background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .entry-content .alignwide,
    body:not(.no-sidebar) .entry-content .alignfull {
        margin-left: -40px;
        width: calc(100% + 80px);
        max-width: calc(100% + 80px);
    }

    @media (max-width:768px) {
        .separate-containers .inside-article,
        .separate-containers .comments-area,
        .separate-containers .page-header,
        .separate-containers .paging-navigation,
        .one-container .site-content,
        .inside-page-header {
            padding: 30px;
        }
        .entry-content .alignwide,
        body:not(.no-sidebar) .entry-content .alignfull {
            margin-left: -30px;
            width: calc(100% + 60px);
            max-width: calc(100% + 60px);
        }
    }

    .rtl .menu-item-has-children .dropdown-menu-toggle {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .rtl .main-navigation .main-nav ul li.menu-item-has-children>a {
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .one-container .sidebar .widget {
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .append_row {
        color: black !important;
        background-color: #FFD6D6 !important;
        border: 1px #ccc solid !important;
    }

    .append_column {
        color: black !important;
        background-color: #D6FFD6 !important;
        border: 1px #ccc solid !important;
    }

    table#my-table td {
        width: 50px;
        height: 27px;
        border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
    }

    div#my-container input {
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 12px !important;
        width: 100px;
        margin: 2px;
    }

    .row {
        background-color: #FFD6D6 !important;
    }

    .col {
        background-color: #D6FFD6 !important;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script>

    // append row to the HTML table
    function appendRow() {
        var tbl = document.getElementById('my-table'), // table reference
            row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length),      // append table row
            i;
        // insert table cells to the new row
        for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
            createCell(row.insertCell(i), i, 'row');
        }
    }

    // create DIV element and append to the table cell
    function createCell(cell, text, style) {
        var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element
            txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
        div.appendChild(txt);                    // append text node to the DIV
        div.setAttribute('class', style);        // set DIV class attribute
        div.setAttribute('className', style);    // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
        cell.appendChild(div);                   // append DIV to the table cell
    }

    // append column to the HTML table
    function appendColumn() {
        var tbl = document.getElementById('my-table'), // table reference
            i;
        // open loop for each row and append cell
        for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
            createCell(tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
        }
    }

    // delete table rows with index greater then 0
    function deleteRows() {
        var tbl = document.getElementById('my-table'), // table reference
            lastRow = tbl.rows.length - 1,             // set the last row index
            i;
        // delete rows with index greater then 0
        for (i = lastRow; i > 0; i--) {
            tbl.deleteRow(i);
        }
    }

    // delete table columns with index greater then 0
    function deleteColumns() {
        var tbl = document.getElementById('my-table'), // table reference
            lastCol = tbl.rows[0].cells.length - 1,    // set the last column index
            i, j;
        // delete cells with index greater then 0 (for each row)
        for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
            for (j = lastCol; j > 0; j--) {
                tbl.rows[i].deleteCell(j);
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <div id="my-container">
    <center><br>
    <input type="button" value="Add row" onclick="javascript:appendRow()" class="append_row"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Add column" onclick="javascript:appendColumn()" class="append_column"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Delete rows" onclick="javascript:deleteRows()" class="delete"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Delete columns" onclick="javascript:deleteColumns()" class="delete"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Delete both" onclick="javascript:deleteColumns();deleteRows()" class="delete"><p></p>
    <table id="my-table" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>Small</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <p></p></center>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used some of the solutions indicated above plus solutions from other postings to come up with a working solution for a dynamic table containing input fields. I'm doing this because it might help someone who finds this thread after searching for the same things that led me to it, and also because the accepted answer (and associated jsfiddle) doesn't actually work! That is, it doesn't index the table rows correctly after a number of inserts/deletes.  The key issue is how to uniquely index the dynamic row data, which is possible with a bit of jquery:

```
<form id=frmLines>
  <table id=tabLines>
  <tr>
    <td>img src='/some/suitable/graphic' onclick='removeLine(this);'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='field1' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='field2' /></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='field3' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='/some/suitable/graphic' onclick='addLine();' /></td>
    <td colspan=3>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Note the form and table have id's for direct DOM referencing, but you can't use id's on the input fields as to make them unique you'd need to introduce an index which would massively complicate the code - and its easy enough to access them by name when the form is processed (see below)

Then the javascript to control adding and removing lines is like this:

```
function addLine() {
  var tabLines = document.getElementById("tabLines");
  var tabLinesRow = tabLines.insertRow(tabLines.rows.length-1);
  var col1html = "<img src='/some/suitable/graphic' onclick='removeLine(this);'>";
  var col2html = "<input type='text' name='field1' />";
  var col3html = "<input type='text' name='field2' />";
  var col4html = "<input type='text' name='field3' />";

  var col1 = tabLinesRow.insertCell(0); col1.innerHTML=col1html;
  var col2 = tabLinesRow.insertCell(1); col2.innerHTML=col2html;
  var col3 = tabLinesRow.insertCell(2); col3.innerHTML=col3html;
  var col4 = tabLinesRow.insertCell(3); col4.innerHTML=col4html;
}

function removeLine(lineItem) {
  var row = lineItem.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

Then the final part of the jigsaw - the javascript to process the form data when its submitted. The key jquery function here is .eq() - which allows you to access the field names in the order they appear in the form - i.e. in table row order.

```
var frmData = {};              // an object to contain all form data
var arrLines = new Array();    // array to contain the dynamic lines

var tabLines = document.getElementById("tabLines").rows.length-1;

for (i=0;i<tabLines;i++) {
  arrLines[i] = {};
  arrLines[i]['no']     = i+1;
  arrLines[i]['field1'] = $("#frmLines input[name=field1]").eq(i).val();
  arrLines[i]['field2'] = $("#frmLines input[name=field2]").eq(i).val();
  arrLines[i]['field3'] = $("#frmLines input[name=field3]").eq(i).val();
}
frmData['lines'] = arrLines;

frmData['another_field'] = $('#frmLines input[name=another_field]").val();

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(frmData);

// lines of data now in a JSON structure as indexed array
// (plus other fields in the JSON as required)
// ready to post via ajax etc
```

I hope this helps someone, either directly or indirectly. There are a couple of subtle techniques being used which aren't that complicated but took me 3-4 hours to piece together.

Answer (score 0):

**[Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces) dynamically adding table data.**

*SCRIPT*

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;    
    var validate_Noof_columns = (colCount - 1); // •No Of Columns to be Validated on Text.
    for(var j = 0; j < colCount; j++) { 
        var text = window.document.getElementById('input'+j).value;

        if (j == validate_Noof_columns) {
            row = table.insertRow(2); // •location of new row.
            for(var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {       
            var text = window.document.getElementById('input'+i).value;
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                if(i == (colCount - 1)) {  // Replace last column with delete button
    newcell.innerHTML = "<INPUT type='button' value='X' onclick='removeRow(this)'/>"; break;
                } else  {
                    newcell.innerHTML = text;
                    window.document.getElementById('input'+i).value = '';
                }
            }   
        }else if (text != 'undefined' && text.trim() == ''){ 
            alert('input'+j+' is EMPTY');break;
        }  
    }   
}
function removeRow(onclickTAG) {
    // Iterate till we find TR tag. 
    while ( (onclickTAG = onclickTAG.parentElement)  && onclickTAG.tagName != 'TR' );
            onclickTAG.parentElement.removeChild(onclickTAG);      
}
```

*HTMl*

```
<div align='center'>
<TABLE id='dataTable' border='1' >
<TBODY>
    <TR><th align='center'><b>First Name:</b></th>
        <th align='center' colspan='2'><b>Last  Name:</b></th>
        <th></th>
    </TR>    
    <TR><TD ><INPUT id='input0' type="text"/></TD>              
        <TD ><INPUT id='input1' type='text'/></TD>
        <TD>
<INPUT type='button' id='input2' value='+' onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY> 
</TABLE>
</div>
```

Example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_Sam/w4q73s99/9/embedded/result/)