# Form Table Style

Tags: html, css

Good Morning everyone.
I'm working on a html page where i need a form similar with the one from the image. It will start from one section of fields and using jquery i will add more and more as needed.
My problem is that i'm not sure how should i design it, i'm thinking using a div that will hold three input fields and from there when i press tab key another div should be added using JavaScript.
I need an advice or example how should i do it.
[image: Sample Form how it should look with multiple fields]

Comment: Did you do your research ? http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/ and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473111/add-delete-table-rows-dynamically-javascript ;)

Comment: Very nice but i'm not sure that i need a table i need to submit data not show data.

Comment: then use `input` objects inside the `TD`s and put the whole table inside a `form`

Comment: yes that would be a second option thank you.