# javascript default appearance of delete button in a row

Tags: javascript, css, html

When I click on the insert row button, I want the delete button also to come default along with the row.
For example

```
function addRow(demo)
  {
    var x=document.getElementById(myTable)'
    var row=x.insertRow(0);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML=demo;
    cell2.innerHTML=(Here I want the delete button to appear);        
  }
```

Also what function should I write to delete the row when the delete button (which is already in each row)is pressed??

Comment: just use `removeattr`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7AeDQ/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add/Delete Table rows Dynamically Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473111/add-delete-table-rows-dynamically-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
    cell1.innerHTML=demo;
    cell2.innerHTML=(Here I want the delete button to appear);        
}
```

Could be changed to:

```
    cell1.innerHTML=demo;
    var delBtn = document.createElement('input');
    delBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    delBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Delete');
    delBtn.addEventListener('click', nameOfYourDelBtnHandlerFunction, false);
    cell2.appendChild(delBtn);
}
```

**EDIT**: sample button-press handler function

```
function onRowDeleteBtn()
{
    var pressedButton = this;                   // must attach the handler with addEventListener, otherwise 'this' will not hold the required value
    var parentCell = pressedButton.parentNode;  // get reference to the cell that contains the button
    var parentRow = parentCell.parentNode;      // get ref to the row that holds the cell, that holds the button
    var parentTbody = parentRow.parentNode;     // get ref to the tbody that holds the row, that holds the cell, that holds the button
    parentTbody.removeChild(parentRow);         // nuke the row element
}
```

Comment: I don't know what is handler function.

Comment: 'handler function' in this instance refers to the code that will be called when the button is pressed - i.e it handles the required response. In your case, you'd want to use it to get a reference to the row that holds the button, before deleting it. I'll add a sample function to my answer in a minute or two.