# How to add a row in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an empty row based on the row that I already have. I have spent an hour looking around and trying different ways but none seem to work. This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="Oretablediv">
<table id="OreTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Ore</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Sub Total</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add Rows?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="Ore">
          <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
          <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="Amount" ></td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>SubTotal</td>
      <td><input type="button" id="delOrebutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="addOrebutton" value="Add More Ore" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function deleteRow(row){
var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById('OreTable').deleteRow(i);
}

function insRow(){
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  var col = document.createElement('td');
  var col2 = document.createElement('td');
  row.appendChild(col);
  row.appendChild(col2);
  var table = document.getElementById("OreTable");
  table.appendChild(row);
}
```

I am currently only asking about the `insRow()` function, if you have suggestions for the delete row please share.

Comment: I’m not sure what you need. Do you want to _clone_ the row where you clicked “Add More Ore” with all the inputs filled out like the row to be cloned? Then try [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and then fill out the fields after that.

Comment: What is not working for you.. What's the problem

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473111/add-delete-table-rows-dynamically-javascript) check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are creating copy of the existing `tr` element, you can achieve this using `cloneNode` instead of creating all the DOM elements using `createElement`

Try this:

```js
function deleteRow(row) {
  var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById('OreTable').deleteRow(i);
}

function insRow() {
  var tr = document.getElementById('toClone');
  var cln = tr.cloneNode(true);
  var elem = cln.querySelector('#Amount');
  elem.value = '';
  var table = document.getElementById("OreTable");
  table.appendChild(cln);
}
```

```html
<div id="Oretablediv">
  <table id="OreTable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Ore</td>
      <td>Amount</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Sub Total</td>
      <td>Delete?</td>
      <td>Add Rows?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='toClone'>
      <td>
        <select name="Ore">
          <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
          <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input size=25 type="text" id="Amount">
      </td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>SubTotal</td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="delOrebutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="addOrebutton" value="Add More Ore" onclick="insRow()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/cos44664/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the click to the button id as follows:

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/c1wsomxp/

```
JAVASCRIPT:

document.getElementById("delOrebutton").onclick = function eleteRow(row){
    var i= this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('OreTable').deleteRow(i+1);
}

document.getElementById("addOrebutton").onclick = function insRow(){
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  var col = document.createElement('td');
  var col2 = document.createElement('td');
  row.appendChild(col);
  row.appendChild(col2);
  var table = document.getElementById("OreTable");
  table.appendChild(row);
} 



HTML:

<div id="Oretablediv">
<table id="OreTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Ore</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Sub Total</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add Rows?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="Ore">
          <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
          <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input size=25 type="text" id="Amount" ></td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>SubTotal</td>
      <td><input type="button" id="delOrebutton" value="Delete" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="addOrebutton" value="Add More Ore"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I have also updated the delete function to delete the first row which was added.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your script will insert the row as a direct child of the "table" tag.  Browsers will often insert a "tbody" tag as a child of the table tag, but a parent to the "tr" tags.  So I think your appendChild(row) call should use the tbody element instead of the table element.

Comment: That’s what I also thought first, but upon testing it, it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: My guess is OP is expecting `td` elements having `input` elements in it..But he is not appending/cloning those elements anywhere..