# Building table with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Essentially I build a table with HTML then will be using Javascript to add more information as I need.

I build the table like so:

```
<form id ="shopping_form">

        <!-- SHOPPING TABLE -->
        <table id = 'items_table' border = 1>
            <tr><th colspan = '2'>Shopping List</th></tr>
            <tr><th>Item</th><th>Price</th></tr>
       </table>
</form>
```

This builds a table and gives it headers. Later I want to use Javascript to add information to the table. I know that I am doing it right logically but am running into some syntax errors somewhere that I can't seem to figure out.

Javascript:

```
//Add items to shopping table
                for(var ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
                {
                    shopping_form.items_table.innerHTML = '<tr>';
                        shopping_form.items_table.innerHTML += '<td>' + itemList[ctr].item + '</td>';
                        shopping_form.items_table.innerHTML += '<td>' + itemList[ctr].price + '.00' + '</td>';
                    shopping_form.items_table.innerHTML += '</tr>';
                }
```

Comment: "some syntax errors somewhere that I can't seem to figure out."  Be more specific.  What errors are you getting and on what lines?

Comment: [Add/Delete table rows dynamically using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473111/add-delete-table-rows-dynamically-using-javascript)

Comment: "syntax errors somewhere that I can't seem to figure out" then you should post a question about those specific errors, rather than asking someone to try and duplicate your setup and figure out what those errors are.  To ask a good question, and to raise your odds of getting a useful answer, you want to *make it as easy as you can* for someone to help you.

Comment: Why aren't you using [insertCell()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) and [insertRow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)  with [createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you cant select DOM element just by typing its id!
you will need to use  [document.getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) to get you element.
then you can start to add text to its inner html as you were doing but you have to use `+=` in the first time to not replace you heading elements.

your js will be:

```
var itemList = [
            {'item': '1', 'price' : '100'},
            {'item': '2', 'price' : '200'},
            {'item': '3', 'price' : '300'},
            {'item': '4', 'price' : '400'},
            {'item': '5', 'price' : '500'}
           ]
//Add items to shopping table
items_table = document.getElementById('items_table');
for(var ctr = 0; ctr < 5; ctr++)
{
    items_table.innerHTML+= '<tr><td>' + itemList[ctr].item + '</td><td>' + itemList[ctr].price + '.00' + '</td></tr>';
}
```

here's a  [Demo example](https://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/qvLrgrde/) for this

**OR**
you can use  [insertRow() and insertCell()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp) methods