# how can i use delete buttons to delete row?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote some code to make a dynamic table. Inserting the data part works ok. But I can't delete the row using the delete button because it's inside the innerHTML.

Does anyone have an idea? I can't figure it out.

```
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td")

//insert row with data
function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(tr.length);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    cell4.innerHTML = '<button type = "button">Delete</button>'
    if(document.getElementById("myRadio").checked){
       cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("myRadio").value
    } else {
     cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("myRadio2").value
    }

    document.getElementById("fname").value = null;//form with no value
    document.getElementById("lname").value = null;//form with no value
    document.getElementById("myRadio").checked = false;//form with no value
    document.getElementById("myRadio2").checked = false;//form with no value    
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473111/add-delete-table-rows-dynamically-using-javascript) work for you?

Comment: this is the first time i have used stack over flow Frankly i really had hard time uploading this question.sorry if i cause some trouble

Comment: You have a `button`, but nothing defined for when the user clicks on the button. Also, you should end each line with a semicolon: `;`.

Comment: appreciate your advice but how can i attach my function to my row ? my table is dynamic , which means it keeps adding row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use deleteRow() function

```js
function deleteRow(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
}
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
  <td>Row 1</td>
  <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 2</td>
  <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 3</td>
  <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[reference from here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp)

You can attach like this.

```
cell4.innerHTML = '<button type = "button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button>';
```

Comment: i cant attach the function to every single row  because my table is dynamic ,which means its rows keeps being inserted

Comment: I've updated my answer. you can append onclick in innerHTML