# how to get row index based on a cell in that row javascript

Tags: javascript

So basically my php file will return an echo (as a table), and in that table, each row will have a cell that is a delete button to delete that row. 
whatI want is when button clicked, the row will be delete from table. So I guess the row index is important to implement this. But how can I get row index in this situation in javascript?

Comment: You don't need to get the rowIndex. Any node can be deleted by `node.parentNode.removeChild(node)`, including table rows. Note that the parent of a row is always a table section element (tbody, thead, tfoot), not the table element.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Add/Delete table rows dynamically using JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473111/add-delete-table-rows-dynamically-using-javascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOM table element has the method [`deleteRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow) and you can get the row index of a table row using [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex) attribute.

```
var myTable = ...
var rowIndex = btn.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
myTable.deleteRow(rowIndex);`
```