# How do I link user input function with the table in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio

I created a Shopping List table with two sections(Grocery Name and Price) in my browser and I have a field for the user to input the name of the grocery. I want, every time when the user enters an item in the field and presses the "ADD" button or enter, for the item to be placed into the table section.

```js
var groceries = []
document.querySelector('#addGroceryForm').addEventListener('submit', addGrocery)


function addGrocery(event) {
  event.preventDefault() //stop the form submission(re-loading the page)
  var groceryInput = document.querySelector('#groceryInput')
  groceries.push(groceryInput.value)
  //Add the new column to the table;
  groceryInput.value = ''

  updateGroceries()
}

function updateGroceries() {
  var groceriesElement = document.querySelector('#groceries')
  groceriesElement.innerHTML = ''

  for (var currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < groceries.length; currentIndex++) {
    var grocery = groceries[currentIndex]
    groceriesElement.innerHTML += '<li>' + grocery + '</li>'
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="addGroceryForm" method='post'>
  <input id='groceryInput' type='text' placeholder="Enter Food">
  <button type='submit'>ADD</button>
</form>

<table class="table-fill">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left">Item</th>
      <th class="text-left">Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class=groceries>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="groceryInput"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left" id='leftOne'> </td>
      <td class="text-left">£</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"> </td>
      <td class="text-left">£</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"> </td>
      <td class="text-left">£</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"> </td>
      <td class="text-left">£</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it seems that you defined groceries as a class, but you call as an id in your js code. Test by editing #groceries with .groceries

Comment: have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473111/add-delete-table-rows-dynamically-using-javascript