# How to add/delete a row in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am working on **html/php** code as shown below.

```
<h3 style="text-align:center;margin-top:45px;">Sitting Days</h3>
<div class="sitting-days" style="display:flex; justify-content:center; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4>
        <input type="date" id="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date" value="<?php if($data->{" house_sitting_date "}<>''){echo $data->{"house_sitting_date "};}?>">
    </div>
    <div class="yes-no">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;">Yes/No</h4>
        <select name="house_sitting_date_yes_no" id="house-yes-no" style="height:24px;">
            <option value="nada" <?php if($data->{"house_sitting_date_yes_no"}=="nada"){echo 'selected';} ?>>Please choose an option</option>
            <option value="yes" <?php if($data->{"house_sitting_date_yes_no"}=="yes"){echo 'selected';} ?>>Yes</option>
            <option value="no" <?php if($data->{"house_sitting_date_yes_no"}=="no"){echo 'selected';} ?>>No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above **html/php** code display the following as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

On hitting **save button**, the above form (as shown in the screenshot) gets saved in the following **JSON file:**

```
$output['house_sitting_date']=$_POST['house_sitting_date'];
$output['house_sitting_date_yes_no']=$_POST['house_sitting_date_yes_no'];

if(file_exists('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json')){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json'));
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what JS code I need to add so that it add/delete rows.

On hitting **+ sign**, it should add one row. On hitting **- sign**, it should delete a row.

When I say add a row, it means add another select of rows.

Comment: When you say "add a row", do you mean another row of selects? And if so, is the intention for all of them to go into one json flie? What do you want the structure of the end json file to look like?

Comment: Yes, correct. Yes I meant to say another select of rows. Yes, it will go in one JSON file. Structure of end JSON file ?

Comment: I am sending you the content of JSON file. `{
 "ptp_status": null,
 "ess_status": null,
 "today_status": null,
 "house_sitting_date": "2020-12-19",
 "house_sitting_date_yes_no": "no",
 "featured_id_en": null,
 "featured_id_fr": null,
 "articles_id_en": null,
 "articles_id_fr": null,
 "twitter_url_en": null,
 "toggle_status": null
}`

Comment: I haven't send you the full content.

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: @bksi We can use jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're tagging jQuery, you can do this with `clone` and `remove` function :

E.g :

HTML:

```
<div class="line-input">
  <input type='text' class='ipt-txt'>
  <input type='submit' class='btn-add' value="add">
  <input type='submit' class='btn-rmv' value="remove">
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("click",".btn-add", function(e){
    $(this).parent(".line-input").clone().insertAfter($(this).parent(".line-input"));
  });

  $(document).on("click",".btn-rmv", function(e){
    $(this).parent(".line-input").remove();
  });

});
```

You can try this fiddle
JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6fqc7n3z/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks great. I will try to make something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786879/add-delete-table-rows-using-javascript)